# New inner class always raise "could not find constructor"

Tags: android, groovy

the full code is [here](https://github.com/roroco/vst/tree/inner-class-cannot-found-constructor), following is my code, when invoke `new PagerAdapter(fragmentManager)`, it always raise `Could not find matching constructor for: ro.vst.Container$PagerAdapter(ro.vst.Container, android.app.FragmentManagerImpl)`

Container.groovy

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.container)
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager)

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(fragmentManager)
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter)
}

class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm)
    }

    @Override
    Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new Slider();
    }

    @Override
    int getCount() {
        return 2
    }
}
```

error:

```
 Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: ro.vst.Container$PagerAdapter(ro.vst.Container, android.app.FragmentManagerImpl)
            at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1723)
            at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1526)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSite.java:46)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:232)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:252)
            at ro.vst.Container.onCreate(Container.groovy:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
```

**update**
even I change code to `PagerAdapter.newInstance(this, fragmentManager)`, the error still exist

Answer (score 1):

Your fragmentManager doesn't match. Both Fragment Manager should be same, either android.app.... or android.support.v4.....

So in your code please try

```
pager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
```

getFragmentManager() is under android.support.v4.app.Fragment

And in your adapter

```
public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}
```

here 'FragmentManager fm' is under android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

Comment: It's not reason, since in groovy, fragmentManager == getFragmentMangger()

Comment: I change it getFragmentManager(), this error still exist

Comment: this shouldn't . In your code there is no chance of causing error. Yet you can change android.app.Fragment to android.support.v4.... in your Slider class. :/

Comment: Yes, you're right, is there way to always don't use android.support.v4, I don't need to support low version android

Comment: There are several support libraries. please read this blog about it. U will understand that when you should use it or not http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/06/android-support-library/